# How can i get all roles with a certain permission

Tags: discord.py

I was creating a ticket system and I wanted it to work in multiple servers but I can't figure out how to get all roles in a server with a certain permission. Or maybe an extra command for people to add roles who can see the channels. But I don't know how?
This is what i have atm:

```py
@bot.command(name='ticket', aliases=['Ticket'])
async def ticket(ctx):
    ticketnum = random.randint(1000,9999)
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(name=f'Ticket-{ticketnum}')
    channel.set_permissions(guild.default_role, read_messages=False)
    await ctx.send(f'Created ticket: {channel}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a `commands.has_permissions()` decorator, or `commands.has_guild_permissions()`, you can use on commands:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True) # Just an example - use the permission you want
@bot.command(...)
async def ticket(ctx):
    # Rest of your code here
```

And this will check that the **user** has the permission available to them.

---

The following code is an equivalent example (not the only way of doing this).

Here is how you'd get all roles with a specific permission:

```py
roles = [r for r in ctx.guild.roles if any(p[1] and p[0] == "administrator" for p in r.permissions)]

# p[1] is checking that the second element of the tuple is True
# As the permissions are returned in the format:
# ("permission_name", boolean)
# Where True is saying the role has the permission enabled
# and False is saying that the role doesn't have the permission
```

And you can use this list to check if the author has any of these roles:

```py
@bot.command(...)
async def ticket(ctx):
    roles = [r for r in ctx.guild.roles if any(p[1] and p[0] == "administrator" for p in r.permissions)]
    if any(r in ctx.author.roles for r in roles):
        # Let the code run
    else:
        # Send an error message
```

---

### **Edit:**

**Method 1:** To set permissions for multiple roles, you can just iterate over each role in the roles list you've created:

```py
@bot.command(...)
async def ticket(ctx):
    # Some code
    roles = [...]
    for role in roles:
        await channel.set_permissions(role, permission_name=True) # Or false
```

That can lead to your bot being rate-limited, so I'd suggest `asyncio.sleep()`ing a bit between each permission update.

**Method 2:** Or when you `create_text_channel()`, you can add in a bunch of overwrites for all the target roles, see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) for an example adding overwrites.

**Method 3:** I would however recommend an easier solution - have a pre-existing target channel with the permissions that you want the new channel to have.
This will enable you to simply `clone()` said channel:

```py
@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
    # Some code
    target_channel = bot.get_channel(112233445566778899)
    new_channel = await target_channel.clone(name="...")
```

And then you can `edit()` the `new_channel`'s position and such if you want.

---

**References:**

- [List comprehensions](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension)
- [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) - Built-in function.
- [`commands.has_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_permissions) - Multiple permissions can be used here as well if so desired.
- [`commands.has_guild_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_guild_permissions)
- [`Guild.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.roles)
- [`discord.Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) - See all the permission names here.
- [`Role.permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.permissions)
- [`Member.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.roles)
- [`TextChannel.edit()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.edit)
- [`TextChannel.clone()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.clone)
- [`Guild.create_text_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) - See permission overwrite example here.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation! But how do i set the permissions for all the roles at once. I want to make it so the people with admin rights and the command author can see it. But the rest of the members dont.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that part. In your question, you added `channel.set_permissions(...)`, but [`set_permissions()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.set_permissions) is actually a coroutine, so you need to `await` it. Otherwise the changes won't take place.

Comment: Yes i found that out already but if I put the varaible roles in the () it wont work
I get this error:
```discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role```

Comment: Yes!!! Method 1 works perfectly. This is just what i needed. Thanks for all your help (-: